# After Update to New Android Studio 3.2 I got error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Desktop\Pulse-AR\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2381: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\Desktop\Pulse-AR\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2398: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\bc8857d6afe6e4598f406355cc075303\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Desktop\Pulse-AR\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

values.xml:2398

```
 <item name="tag" type="id">tag</item>
```

Above error gives in after update new AndroidStudio(3.2) with Update Gradle (gradle-4.6-all)

Comment: As your error is in the intermediate generated files, switch to Project view(instead of Android), expand (your-project)->app->build and delete the _generated_ and _intermediates_ folder, then Clean and Rebuild the project.

Comment: I followed your steps, still I got same error.

Comment: try `Invalidate Catches/Restart`.

Comment: Usually it is worth waiting for the x.y.1 (3.2.1 in this case) version, because the number of bugs in big releases of Android Studio is huge ;)

Comment: Have the same issue, let me know if you found a solution

Comment: Update your SDK and SDK Tools and try.

Comment: @UmangBurman updated SDK, SDK Tools, tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, even deleted from Project the generated and intermediates folder, but still get the same issue, any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting `.gradle` folder from Users folder in Windows. Before that close android studio. @rosualin

Comment: @UmangBurman  I have delete the folder .idea, .gradle, gradle and app\build , But still error.

Comment: Same here, the issue persists

Comment: @ViralPatel Try deleting this line from values.xml `<item name="tag" type="id">tag</item>`

Comment: @UmangBurman, If I delete the line it comes automatically again when I build project.

Comment: for me this is causing the issue: `<item name="header_view" type="id">header_view</item>` But even if I delete that, it will be reset there, being a build file. how can I fix this? Is this like a layout or something?
I don't understand from where this header_view comes, cause I have nothing like that in my project

Comment: Oh, It's the built-in item id which is colliding with your type="id" .. There is a <item tag called type="id" already exists so you can't use that. @ViralPatel

Comment: Try this syntax in your Values.xml `<item type="id" name="id_name" />`

Comment: First type the id and then the name guys. and try

Comment: I show this kind of solution But it's not help me to solve my problem.

Comment: @UmangBurman I  don't understand this. I literally have no header_view in my code, so how does it generate it on build?

Comment: @UmangBurman thanks for the help, I found my issue, one of my libraries was causing the issue. updated it to the latest version and now it works.
This was the cause: https://github.com/bgogetap/StickyHeaders
I was using 0.5.0 instead of 0.5.1

Comment: Actually these type of errors occurs when 2 resources collide.. The OS gets confused from which the data to be taken, and hence we must be very careful in adding the dependencies

Answer (score 7):

Have been working through this problem all day, lots of head scratching.

What worked for me was going into the **ids.xml**, and removing all values between the item tags of **"type=id"**

For example:

```
<item type="id" name="icon">textToBeRemoved</item>
```

Goes to

```
<item type="id" name="icon"></item>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: TheMan, Read comments carefully then gives your reply.

Comment: You referenced values.xml, which is created at build, whereas ids.xml isn't. Seeing as nobody before had referenced it I thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: Worth noting that you can override a resource from a library this way and fix the build.

Comment: Worth noting that you can override a resource from a library this way and fix the build.

Answer (score 3):

Try add below option inside `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: `Process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Answer (score 2):

go to ids.xml file

replace `<item name="tag" type="id">tag</item>` with `<item name="tag" type="id"/>`

if this tag `<item name="tag" type="id">tag</item>` is not exist, then mean that tag is inside the library you are using, so just add the tag `<item name="tag" type="id"/>` for override it from the library.

after you override that tag, you can  find which library is using that tag by find usage , and fix that library.